# Icons aren't colored as set in menu.xml, which I include in other .xml file

Tags: xml, android-studio, icons

I am wondering why my icons in menu.xml file which are set to some color, aren't colored after I include the menu.xml in other .xml file. See the screenshot, I can provide more info if needed.

Thank you for your time.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mainactivity,

```
 navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```